# Is Firebase Firestore working in React Native Expo?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, expo

I found out some documentation in official expo forum about firestore and everything seems to be working. And I were able to implement whole login, sign up flow with various providers from firebase. But I can not run any query from firestore. I am doing it like this:

```
const[dataSource, setDataSource] = React.useState({});

const getMealTypes = (mealTypes) =>{
  const Meals = [];
  mealTypes.get().then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          const {title, count} = doc.data();
          Meals.push({
            key: doc.id,
            title,
            count
          })
          } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
  console.log(Meals);
  setDataSource(Meals);
}


React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
    const mealTypes = firebase.firestore().collection('mealTypes');
    getMealTypes(mealTypes);
    setDataSource([]);
}, []);
```

I have tried many more ways to get that response, but it never go into promise after get() function. Is get() broken in expo or am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

what version of firebase? there was a regression in support for react-native in the javascript sdk for firebase recently and the team is working on resolving that, until then i would recommend using version 7.9.0, which you will get if you run `expo install firebase` with the latest version of `expo` installed in your project

Comment: I am using "firebase": "^7.14.0". Should I downgrade to 7.9.0?